# Basic Java Syntax Questions

Tags: java

I am doing a homework assignment (I am not one to lie) and I am honestly stumped at the questions.  I have 3 years of programming experience but am stumped on some of the simplest problems in the class, lol.  New to Java, not new to programming rather.  I would like to discuss why the questions result in an answer and why it is one way or another.

1) Write 3.4, is this a double or a float?

I want to say its a float by default, as it takes up less space (32 bits) versus a double (64) bits.  Since 3.4 is a small number, I would assume it is a float?

2) Declare x as a double and assign it the value of 3.4 (as a double).

I think it is `double x = 3.4d;` not 100% sure on this

3) Declare y as a float and assign it the value 3.4 (as a float).

Similar to above, i think it is `float y = 3.4f;`

Not usually one to come on here and ask for HW help in this manner...but I have no textbook for another week as I just ordered it.  I would rather like to discuss why it is one way or another so I can get a better understanding of how Java works.  Thanks.

Comment: Check the section "Floating-Point literals" here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first question, `3.4` is a `double`. If you wanted a `float` literal, you would use `3.4f`.

---

Second question:

```
double x = 3.4; // trailing D/d is optional and rarely used.
```

---

Third question, you're correct, declare it as `float` and use the `f` suffix on the literal.

---

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for more details, specifically the section entitled `Floating-Point Literals`, copied here, with minor modifications for emphasis:

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it ends with the letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally end with the letter D or d.
>
> The floating point types (float and double) can also be expressed using **E** or **e** (for scientific notation), **F** or **f** (32-bit float literal) and **D** or **d** (64-bit double literal; *this is the default and by convention is omitted).*

```
double d1 = 123.4;
double d2 = 1.234e2; // same value as d1, but in scientific notation
float f1  = 123.4f;
```

Comment: Why does Java choose to use double by default instead of float?

Comment: Because that's what the specs say. C and C++ do a similar thing. To be brutally honest, floats were useful back in the olden days but, unless you have a real pressing need for smaller range/storage, you should be using doubles.

Answer (score 1):

1. 3.4 is a double, put a `f` after it to get a float.
2. Correct, but remember to put a `;` in the end of the line.
3. Same as above.

Comment: Derp on the `;`.  I'm curious, why are they doubles by default?

Comment: Floats are not as accurate, they want you to specify that you don't need the higher accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Java float literals are double by default, just as if you specified `d` modifier. If you want 32-bit floats, you have to explicitly state the `f` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

1. By Default java considers float literals as double. Hence 3.4 is double.
2. double x = 3.4;
3. What you have written is correct.

Comment: Just one nitpick, jack, decimal refers to the base (10), so 3 is as much decimal as 3.4. I suspect you meant to say floating point rather than decimal. Not that it detracts from your answer, it's just that sometimes I feel rather anal retentive :-)

Comment: Yeah makes sense, fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

if it is float means you have to declare like this float y = 3.4**f**  .f indicates to jvm it is a float.if u forget that f (3.4f) it will treat as double by default and it takes 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

```
I'm curious, why are they doubles by default
```

(IMHO) I think high precision is better than low precision. Java (same thing in C as well) can  downconvert to float when you try to, so this thing doesn't cause problems.